# Configuring Passenger Server and Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, virtualhost, passenger

I have a rails application which I want to run on the default port 80 via apache. So I setup the Passenger server and I configured the apache configuration file.

My application used to run on the default 3000 port and my routes.rb looks like this :

```
ScwCentral::Application.routes.draw do
 resources :smoke
 resources :regression
.....
....
.....
```

These are the 2 controllers in my application 'smoke' and 'regression'. So my application would run on a url such as localhost:3000/smoke and localhost:3000/regression.

Now after setting up the Passenger server and everything, I edited the apache config file to this:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby

# Rails_App Virtual Host

<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                         
  ServerName www.mysite.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /a/rails_app_test/public/    
  <Directory /a/rails_app_test/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
```

where "/a/rails_app_test/' is the path of my application.

Now when I go to www.mysite.com it says

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/"
```

When I open www.mysite.com I would ideally want to open localhost:3000/smoke. Do I need to make any more changes in the configuration file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a root route. For example, if you did

`rails g controller welcome index`

and then added

`root :to => 'weclome#index'`

Your root path / would show the welcome index page.